# Externalize strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string-externalization

I have been searching on line for a tool that externalized strings in JavaScript but I have been unable to do so. I was hoping there would be something similar to the one built into eclipse (Source -> Externalize Strings...). If someone knows of a tool or plugin for eclipse that could accomplish that, let me know.

We have a software project that is already mature but now needs to support translations, and hence we need the string externalized.

Comment: data belongs in HTML, styles belong in CSS, interactions belong in JS. if you're doing translations, it sounds like you should be reading HTML content/attributes/hidden data to get the correct text.

Comment: With dynamically generated pages, a lot of the strings do come from JS

Comment: do you mean they come from AJAX, or are the strings hard-coded in JS?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a JSON-based language look-up table if you want to populate these values via JavaScript. Eclipse cannot help you with this.

See: [Localization in a web app using JavaScript and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090641/localization-in-a-web-app-using-javascript-and-json)

Comment: This is for the look-up table. It doesn't seem to help get the strings out of the javscript code. I could be wrong, if so, let me know :)

Comment: The JSON file can stand-alone without being part of the actual JS code, and can also be fetched via AJAX.